# Incrementing integer value in a column in a specific row

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a table containing a list of URLs and the number of times they have been visited. Using python, how do I create an SQL query that increments the HITS column for a specific URL? i.e. a specific row?

So far I have:

```
def insertURL(url) :
    ##query to fetch all URLs
    sql = "SELECT URL_visited FROM URL"

    ##query to insert a number into the HITS column
    insert_sql = "INSERT INTO URL_visited (total_hits)"
    insert_sql = insert_sql + "VALUES('"+1+"')"

    ##execute sql query to fetch URLs 
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    ##flag to check whether the URL already exists in table
    flag = 0 

    ##checking if URL exists
    for row in results:
        if (row==url) :
            flag = 1 

    ##if yes, increment HITS column for that URL (specific row)
    if flag == 1 :
        ##how to do??
```

As you can see, I can insert a number into the HITS column but how do I just increment the value at a specific row?

Comment: You should get the value from the specific row and then update the value plus 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimized approach: just *update/increment* `total_hits` column value for a particular `url_visited` value:

(considering `urls` is a target table name)

```
def update_url_hits(url):
   sql_query = "UPDATE urls SET total_hits = total_hits + 1 WHERE url_visited = %"
   cursor.execute(sql_query, (url,))
   connection.commit()
```